# How to add CSS to a particular row in a table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a table as below

```
<table className="TableClass">
  <tbody>
    <tr row="0">
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr row="1">
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I just need to add CSS to the `<tr row="0">` only. will that be possible ?

Comment: CSS: table tr:first-child { background: red; }

Comment: CSS #2: tr[row="0"] { background: red; }

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[attribute=value] selector`

```css
tr[row="0"] { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table className="TableClass">
<tbody>
<tr row="0">
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
<tr row="1">
  <td>Data</td>
  <td>Data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply styling on elements with certain attributes in **CSS** you can use the ***attribute selector***.
The syntax for attribute selector is

```
elementName [attribute = value]
```

So, you can just apply styling to the row 1 like this:

```
tr[row="0"]{
/*all styles here*/
}
```